# play button and progress bar of jplayer not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jplayer

I put jplayer in my joomla site for playing my mp3 files. The problem is play button and the progress bar of the jplayer not working in my site when using Firefox. I added the "add type ogg" in my htaccess. The ogg file is playing in my site but there is no ogg file display when I inspect the element using firebug. I can find only a disabled code that is:

```
<div class="jp-jplayer" id="jquery_jplayer_1" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    <img id="jp_poster_0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;" src=" images/jmplayer/albums/thumb_13520917357864.jpeg">
    <object width="1" height="1" id="jp_flash_0" data="js/Jplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    <param name="flashvars" value="jQuery=jQuery&amp;id=jquery_jplayer_1&amp;vol=0.8&amp;muted=false">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque"></object>
</div>
```

here is my link : http://www.keralacarpentry.com/saavnnew

Comment: please check my site link : http://keralacarpentry.com/saavnnew/

Comment: http://www.keralacarpentry.com/ lists all the files in the directory... that is not good...

Comment: please find the site : http://www.keralacarpentry.com/saavnnew

Answer (score 0):

Actually jPlayer use `html 5` audio tags and firefox does not support `mp3 files` on `audio` tag
[W3schools Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp)

Other References:

[Why doesn't Firefox support mp3 file format in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923136/why-doesnt-firefox-support-mp3-file-format-in-audio)

[why is jPlayer not playing my MP3 files in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655341/why-is-jplayer-not-playing-my-mp3-files-in-firefox)

Comment: thanks for your replay. My jplayer is playing the ogg file in fire fox.The problem is play button and progress bar is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesnot support mp3 files , but to make it play using jplayer make sure that you have install Flash in firefox and include swf path in javascript as bellow

```
$("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "http://sound26.mp3pk.com/indian/ladiesvsricky/ladiesvsrickybahl01(www.songs.pk).mp3" } );
    },
    //swfPath: "http://cloudfactory-transcription.s3.amazonaws.com/javascripts/",
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "mp3",
    volume: 1,
    wmode:"window",
    solution: "html,flash",
});
```

Jplayer play mp3 files in firefox using flash only.

Comment: thanks for your replay.My jplayer is playing in fire fox ,but the problem is play button and progress bar is not working.


Please give me an advise

Answer (score 0):

For #jquery_jplayer_1, you bind twice: 

1. in line 693

2. when $('#playallinner').click, you bind again.

Suggest to modify:

1. remove code from 693 to 703

```
        /*
        var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
           jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
           cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
         }, {
          playlistOptions: {
                  enableRemoveControls: true
          },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
        });
         */
```

And then:
2. change code from 1794, like:

```
//new a jPlayerlist object
var playallList = new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, {
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
});
// add list into the list
playallList.setPlaylist([           
           {
             title:"Aadhai Aaula",
             artist:"Mipa",
             .... // list all songs you want
           },

]);
//play the list when the play button be clicked.
$('#playallinner').click(function(){
     playallList.play();
     var playcount = /*parseInt($("#playtotal").html())+*/ 6;
     $("#playtotal").text(playcount);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your great reply.But i implemented this to my program but i can't find any change.The problem is still with firefox.